# Find Record based on the associated attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree

I am trying to find a record based on two associated attributes. The Record should be selected, if its association contains those two records.

So far, I tried following - Which seemed to me a very bad practice and I want to avoid using it.

```
@size = Spree::OptionValue.find(params[:size])
@color = Spree::OptionValue.find(params[:color])

vari = Spree::Variant.all
vari.each do |va|
  if va.option_values.include?(@size && @color)
    @variant = va
  end
end
```

So far, I also tried

```
@variant = Spree::Variant.all(:include => :option_values, :conditions => ['option_value.id = ?', params[:color])
```

This seems to be the way to go, but I can't seem to figure out the right way to get the result.
The return error I keep on getting is following:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "option_values"
>   LINE 1: ..._option_values_variants"."option_value_id" WHERE (option_val...

EDIT:

I got it working due to the great help given in the accepted answer:

```
Spree::Variant.joins(:option_values).where("spree_option_values.id in (?)", [size, color])
```

Comment: try to make it `option_values.id`, like the association.

Comment: That doesnt solve the issue, sadly.

Comment: Really need to see your models and associations to make any sense of this.

Comment: I just looked at the source.  It's a habtm.  https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/db/migrate/20120831092320_spree_one_two.rb

Comment: Thank you, yes - its a HABTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your code is probably broken. I doubt that `.include?(@size && @color)` does what you think it does; you're effectively only checking if `option_values` includes `@color`. This is equivalent to doing `(true && @color)`. If you want to include *both* values, you need `.include?(@size) && .include?(@color)`.

So your code should probably look like this:

```
vari = Spree::Variant.all
vari.each do |va|
  if va.option_values.include?(@size) && va.option_values.include?(@color)
    @variant = va
  end
end
```

Next, you can make your code much more Ruby-esque:

```
@variant = Spree::Variant.all.select do |v|
  v.option_values.include?(@size) && v.option_values.include?(@color)
end
```

But it's far better to actually evaluate the condition at the database level rather than load the entire table into your application. You seem to be looking for all records where the associated `OptionValue`s includes the two you've selected into `@size` and `@color`.

The query you're looking for probably looks something like this:

```
Spree::Variant.joins(:option_values).where("option_values.id in (?)", [@size, @color])
```

Comment: This seems to be the way to go for me. If I'm trying to confirm the functionality in the console, I keep on getting following return  > ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3fd43f225ef4

Comment: Because Rails is giving you a relation, ready for additional scope/where/join chaining. You need to *use* it for Rails to turn it into a list of records; using `.all` would do the trick.

Comment: Ah. I seem to understand. Sadly, this results in NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007fa88126e158>. I don't know, why this handled as Array?

Comment: No, sorry, you need to add `.all` to the very end of the statement, before the `.where`.

Comment: Thats what I was doing. > Spree::Variant.joins(:spree_option_values).all.where("option_values.id in ?", [@size, @color])

Comment: Argh, sorry, I mistyped. You need to add it to the **end** of the statement. I meant to say *after* the where.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be more or less doing what I should. But it returns with the wonderful statement: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "553775723"
LINE 1: ...nts"."option_value_id" WHERE (option_values.id in 553775723,...) I'm sorry, I keep on coming back with this problem, but I'm really out of gas on this one.

Comment: Problem solved - needed to wrap the ? in (). I'll edit the working query in the top.